# Обтекание контейнеров

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, css3

Есть контейнеры с свойством `float:left`под каждым контейнером. Контейнер с описанием при добавлении больше одного слова. Обтекание нарушается в том месте, где добавили второе слово. Помогите решить проблему. Проблема на моем сайте http://prorab-service.ru/new/index.php. А здесь правильное обтекание http://prorab-service.ru/new/masters/masters.php.

Описание

Comment: Что значит не правильное обтекание? Текст вылазит?

Comment: Есть 8 контейнеров с фиксированной шириной, под контейнером название название  если писать  одно слово проблем нет а если 2 слова с пробелом между ними в этом месте следующие контейнеры начинаются с новой строки. Выше есть сылка пройдите.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/hEOro7r.jpg. Покажите мне на фотке, где проблема?

Comment: Нижние два контейнера должны уйти в лево, а из-за того что я написал "строительные материалы" она не уходит.

Comment: @Ruslan Перенесите, пожалуйста, код со стороннего ресурса сюда, создав минимальный и воспроизводимый пример нежелательного поведения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените стили на эти:

```
#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #f8bbd0;
}

#m {
  width: 130px;
  margin: 50px 30px 10px 30px;
  padding: 0;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}
```

И не используйте `float: left`. Это устарелый метод реализации

Comment: Не помогает, посмотрите во вторую ссылку там нет такой проблемы как в первой

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает

Comment: @Ruslan, что бы работало, нужно установить всем блокам фиксированную высоту